# Spring security saml with rest api and angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-security, spring-saml, spring-rest

I am working on prototype application where my application is built with following frameworks
-- spring mvc (rest api)
-- angular 2(frontend)
-- spring security with saml
-- ssocircle (public IDP)
-- maven as build tool

I have successfully built this project and is available on github and tested with both tomcat 8.0 and weblogic 12.1.3. Also this whole project is packaged as single war. Generally I noticed that people built angular 2 app separately and backend api separately. I am not sure which one is best practice but any recommendation is welcome.

https://github.com/pritspatel/spring-saml-angular2.git

Now i want to expand this project a little further where

1. Once user is authenticated by IDP, i want to redirect to home page of the angular 2 app
2. while i redirect to angular 2 home page, i want to pass auth token(JWT) generated based on Saml token. If this is not a good practice then please let me know
3. Send jwt on every subsequent request from angular 2 app
4. secure rest api and provide ACL based on user role which will be controlled in db.

I am new to Angular 2 and spring security saml, so please correct me if i am wrong on any best practice.